# Setting AsyncTask progress for SQLite - cannot get progress percentage

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I have created a splash screen for my app to hide the periodic insertion (after publishing updates) of a large number of records into the different tables of my app's SQLite database. I have been implementing an AsyncTask to handle the insertion off of the UI thread.

I need to create a ProgressDialog (with progress bar, not the simple spinning wheel) to inform the user of the current progress percentage for the insertion operations.

In most examples for setting the dialog's progress bar, the counter variable for the for loop representing the lengthy operation, or the percentage of file download is used to set this progress for the dialog. However, since insertions into different tables may take different amounts of time (depending on number of columns, etc), this approach appears to fail. The closest solution I could see would be to write a publishProgress(some_percentage) line after every record insertion in my doInBackground() method, using the % of records inserted as the parameter for publishProgress(), but this seems like a terribly inelegant and inefficient practice.

The current code for my AsyncTask implementation is below. Any suggestions for the best practice of determining the current progress percentage would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
private class InsertionAction extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Void> {

    Context context;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    private ForwardAction(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        this.dialog.setMessage("Initializing Database. Please Wait...");
        this.dialog.show();
        this.dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        this.dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // Large block of record insertions


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        // Forward to the main activity
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        animatedTransition(SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME/2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    }

}
```

Comment: By "Large block of record insertions" do you mean lots of lines of java code or is there some loop that goes through lots of  inserts?

Comment: Loss of lines. It's currently at ~900 lines, and grows as I improve the database.

Comment: You should consider changing your update schema, like putting all the updates in a textfile containing raw sql commands so you just need to read the file line by line and execute the command. Otherwise there is not much you can do but to put a `publishProgress` at several locations.

Comment: @avoyles : 900 lines of Java to update a database...seriously? You're doing something very badly wrong when it comes to your design approach.

Comment: @Squonk : Yes, I realize that that is a poor approach. The database has been something I haven't worked much on improving, as the table in question used to only contain ~40 records, each one pertaining to a particular golf course. However, as the number of courses that we support has grown dramatically lately, the number of corresponding records in the database has as well. My current approach on updating the app version (when new courses would be added) was to drop that table, and rebuild it to the new version, by adding all those records to the table, hence many lines to insert many records

Comment: @Squonk : I have been considering doing something along the lines of what zapl suggested of parsing an external text file. If you have any better suggestions of how to perform the updates, I would greatly appreciate the insight - SQLite database stuff is very new to me. My main reason for the crude update method of dropping, and then re-inserting all the new records was to try and avoid adding/removing records accidentally.

Comment: @avoyles : Dropping the table each time is the least of your problems. If you're modifying the Java code each time a golf course (or several) is/are added then that's a non-sustainable approach. It make things much more manageable if you maintain a central source of all data - this could be anything from a CSV file format to XML, JSON and so on. All you then need to do is iterate through the source and add each record with exactly the same bit of code. It would take a few dozen lines of code at most and the code would never need to change - just the data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to programmatically count your lines of code, calculate how much time they need to execute and generate an accurate time-proportionate progress.

I suggest updating the progress bar after a certain interval of lines, e.g. every 90 inserts (10%).

Or update according to what you are doing and modify the progress message (try to be creative), e.g. "Adding users", "Generating death rays", "Creating the universe", "Just a little longer", etc.